# Запрос на получение таблицы из EAV

Tags: mysql, eav

Есть структура.

Таблица продуктов:

```
Product
id | name | price
```

Таблица возможных полей (пополняется через админку):

```
Attr_list
id | title
```

Таблица с самими полями:

```
Attributes
id | product_id | title | value
```

В итоге хочу получить выборку вида:

```
id | name | price | Заголовок поля N | Заголовок поля N
01 | Имя  | 40000 | Значение поля N | Значение поля N
```

Количество дополнительных полей заранее неизвестно.

Помогите составить запрос, мучаюсь, получаю таблицу в N строк, где N = количество доп полей.

Comment: Это невозможно сделать одним запросом. Набор колонок должен быть задан сразу. Можно только посмотрев одним запросом возможный набор колонок динамически сгенерировать другой запрос, который уже вытянет данные. А вообще лучше бы это разворачивать уже при получении, на клиенте

Comment: подскажите тогда как правильно реализовать один из вариантов?

Comment: "Один из" это какой ? клиентский язык вы не указали. а на нем это делать на порядок проще, чем на sql. Хотя вроде все не так уж и плохо ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: пишу все на php. B какую таблицу мне требуется получить для обработки?

Comment: вот php вариант https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994890/pdo-pivot-a-table

Comment: хотя надо потом еще решить как полученный развернутый массив на экран выводить. опять же потребуется в отдельном массиве собрать список возможных элементов что бы шапку таблицы отрисовать